# Creating a data.table row by row

Tags: r, data.table

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)

data <- structure(list(Choice_07 = c(1, 1), Choice_08 = c(0, 1), Choice_09 = c(1, 
1), Choice_10 = c(0, 1), Choice_11 = c(1, 1), Choice_12 = c(0, 
1), Compare_Tax_below_norm_B = c(0, 0), treatment = structure(c(0, 
1), label = NA_character_, class = c("labelled", "numeric")), 
    Penalty = structure(c(1, 0.5), label = "Wie hoch schätzt der Markt den Gewinn pro Aktie für die Castor AG ein?", class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), New_Compare_Tax = structure(c(3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "0", "2"), class = "factor"), New_Compare_Truth = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("1", "0", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I want to create a new data.frame row by row, as follows:

```
other_data = data.frame()
other_data [1,] <- setDT(data)[New_Compare_Tax == 0,lapply(Filter(is.numeric,.SD),sum, na.rm=TRUE)]
```

However, this creates no variables, while the following for some reason does work.

```
tmp <- setDT(data)[New_Compare_Tax == 0,lapply(Filter(is.numeric,.SD),sum, na.rm=TRUE)]
other_data = data.frame()
other_data <- tmp[1,]
```

Could anyone tell me how to do this directly?

Comment: Can you provide your expected output.

Comment: @MohanGovindasamy I have already provided the expected output. I think you maybe got confused because I made a typo in the post.

Comment: The `dput` provides a list. Also, why do you want to do this? what is the ultimate goal?

Comment: @RonakShah I was collecting rows from different datasets, so I thought the easiest thing to do would be to collect the rows like in the post.

Comment: The `other_data[1, ]` seems problematic for an empty data.frame. You may be on better track using `other_data = list(); other_data[[1L]] = data[...]`

Comment: I still don't get it. You can collect rows from different datasets and use `rbind` using `rbind(df1[1, ], df2[1, ], ....)` and so on. I am not sure why you think you need an empty dataframe to begin with.

Comment: @RonakShah I guess you are right, but for some reason that did not come to mind..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an object `df_tax`. Assuming `df_tax` is actually `data`, you can get the single row data table that is the sum of numeric variables in `data` for which `New_Compare_Tax` is zero (note that it is never zero in your example dataset; it only takes on values 2 and 1) by doing this:

```r
setDT(data)[New_Compare_Tax==0][, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=T), .SDcols=is.numeric]
```

If you wanted that sum over all numeric variables *for each value of* `New_Compare_Tax`, you can do this:

```r
setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=T), .SDcols=is.numeric, by=New_Compare_Tax]
```

Comment: My apologies, `df_tax` is indeed `data`, I will change this. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I am still getting no variables, when applying your solution.

Comment: @Tom , it works.  I don't know what you are doing, I can only guess you are still doing something like `other.data[1,]<-<my solution>`, which will not work. (perhaps try `other.data<-<my solution>`)

Comment: And if you are doing this separately for many data sources, that all have a similar structure as `data`, say `my_list_of_data = list("data1" = data1, "data2" = data2, "data3" = data3)`, and you later want to combine them into a single dataframe, then do something like `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(my_list_of_data, function(x) <my solution using x>))`